# Where to place AlarmManager for Notifications

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm building an application in which I need I run a check every 12 Hours and give notifications accordingly. For this, I used an AlarmManager that repeats each 12 hours and fires a notification if the conditions are met:

**MainActivity (Inside the *onCreate* Method):**

```
//Set Notifications AlarmManager
AlarmManager AM = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent (this, NotificationAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() + 5000); //5 Seconds from now
AM.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY , pending); //12 Hour Interval
```

The notifications are functioning correctly, however, I think I'm making a mistake by placing the AlarmManager in the `onCreate` method, because now everytime the user opens the application the AlarmManager is reset. However, I don't know where else I can initiate it where it will only be created one time instead of being repeatedly created each time the main Activity is opened.

I have a feeling it has something to do with `Service` however I have don't know how to use Services yet so I'm not quite sure about that

Comment: You are correct in believing that onCreate is not the optimal location.

Comment: Yes I have thought so, there are a lot of tutorials about `AlarmManager` and Notifications. But I wish one of them just mentioned where to actually place the code

Comment: Also, when using AlarmManager - you should be aware that PendingIntents are cleared when the device turns off. Use an IntentService for the task of scheduling the alarm (still a Service, but easier). To take care of rescheduling the alarm when the device is rebooted - you should use a BroadcastReceiver to listen for Intent.BOOT_COMPLETED - use this Broadcast Receiver to reschedule the IntentService you created.

Comment: I have already added this to the Manifest to solve the rescheduling problem:

        <receiver
            android:name=".NotificationAlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: @apelsoczi Would keeping the AlarmManager and using a boolean flag stored in SharedPref to decide whether to run the code or not be a good idea ?

Comment: the documentation states: If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled. What I would do, is to keep everything you have currently, use Calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, XXX) where XXX would be the difference in time until your next interval, either 00:00 or 12:00 as an example. (PS: when using Calendar.add() the internal fields are not calculated, use Calendar.getDate() to force Calendar class to recompute, you won't be interested in the Date which this method returns.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115745/discussion-between-apelsoczi-and-a-wali).

Comment: @apelsoczi Thank you for your response. However, I didn't understand your point about changing the calendar part, where should I change those and what effect would the change make ?

Comment: Nevermind, on second glance. You did call a method which recomputes the Calendar internal fields. However, as a word of advice and caution: instead of `cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() + 5000); //5 Seconds from now` use: `cal.add(Calendar.SECONDS, 5);` .... checkout one of my methods on github where I use 3 calendar objects in one method to compare each other. NOTICE: I never perform arithmetic on Calendars, and comparisons are done with Date objects. https://github.com/apelsoczi/NFCAlarm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/adam/nfcalarm/data/AlarmDAO.java#L120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While setting Alarm, you should check if Alarm exists or not. If not
>   existing that alarm then create new alarm. This way will save you from
>   creating multiple alarms.

```
private void setAlarmIfRequired() {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationAlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        if (pendingIntent == null) {
            // There is no alarm set for same
            //Set Notifications AlarmManager
            AlarmManager AM = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() + 5000); //5 Seconds from now
            AM.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY , pending); //12 Hour Interval
        }
    }
```

In above example I used the code which you posted into question.

---

Update1: Better is to move this method to utility class and make it as static method, so you can call it from Activity or the receiver where you listen device-boot.

Code would be like

```
public static void setAlarmIfRequired(Context context) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationAlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        if (pendingIntent == null) {
            // There is no alarm set for same
            //Set Notifications AlarmManager
            AlarmManager AM = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() + 5000); //5 Seconds from now
            AM.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY , pending); //12 Hour Interval
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what I understand is that I should change the `PendingIntent` Flag to `FLAG_NO_CREATE` and check for null before calling the Alarm

However, I have a question about this: Should I still call this function in my onCreate Method of MainActivity?

Comment: Now there is no problem if you are calling this method from Activity, because it only create the alarm if not set. But yes, you need to look for better place where you should optimize this method call. One more option is, you can call this method from 'Application's onCreate' if it fits to your application requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I usually start an alarm on an event so it depends on the user interaction and not on the activity lifecycle. For example, I did when the user presses a button.

If you don't want to let him or her start the alarm, then you have to use a service and call it from the activity only if it is not already running.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Your alarm will then have its own lifecycle and will not be reset.

Comment: I don't have an event to start the Alarm on, I just want it to set it once for the whole application once the application is ran for the first time

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to set it using a service please?

Comment: Follow the link, it is enough elaborated in the Android documentation ;)